# google map api to picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps

I need to fill my picturebox (or panel) with google map, but it won't whenever I change size in url. How to do that, or is there a better provider (msn, openstreetmap ...ect)?

```
   string urlmaps = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.56,4.48&size=600x600&sensor=true&format=png&maptype=roadmap&zoom=10";


        var request = WebRequest.Create(urlmaps);
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PictureBox.Load(string url)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx) to load the remote image directly into the picure box.